# Find $E(Y)$ such that $F_Y(y)= (1 - 0. 3e^{−0.5} + 0. 6e^{−0.25y})$

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, cumulative-distribution-functions

> Find $E(Y)$ such that the cumulative density function of $Y$ is: $$F_Y(y)= (1 - 0. 3e^{−0.5} + 0. 6e^{−0.25y})$$

Can someone help me figure out how to calculate the mean?

Comment: Please update your question to let us know what you have tried so far

Comment: You can use [math notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) in posting here.  As to your problem, you should do some calculus and apply the definitions.  It's unclear (because of the lack of context) where you had difficulty, or why you needed to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you convinced that this is a valid distribution?

Comment: Even with your recent edit you still don't have a CDF.  At $y=0$ it is larger than 1 and it is continuously decreasing as opposed to it being non-decreasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have provided is likely 1 minus a cumulative distribution function but with at least one typo.

You gave

$$0.3 e^{-0.5 y}+0.6 e^{-0.25 y}$$

A plot of that function is

[image: Plot of function given by OP]

This function needs to be 1 when $y=0$.  To obtain that you probably need

$$0.3 e^{-0.5 y}+0.7 e^{-0.25 y}$$

or

$$0.4 e^{-0.5 y}+0.6 e^{-0.25 y}$$

or in general the weights need to be between 0 and 1 and sum to 1:

$$w e^{-0.5 y}+(1-w) e^{-0.25 y}$$

Suppose we take

$$Pr(Y>y)=0.4 e^{-0.5 y}+0.6 e^{-0.25 y}$$

Then the cumulative distribution function is

$$Pr(Y\leq y)=1-0.4 e^{-0.5 y}-0.6 e^{-0.25 y}$$

The probability density function is

$$f(y)=0.2 e^{-0.5 y}+0.15 e^{-0.25 y}$$

The mean is given by

$$\mu =\int_0^{\infty } y \left(0.2 e^{-0.5 y}+0.15 e^{-0.25 y}\right) \, dy=3.2 $$

and the variance

$$\sigma^2=\int_0^{\infty }(y-\mu )^2  \left(0.2 e^{-0.5 y}+0.15 e^{-0.25 y}\right) \, dy=12.16$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I have a question though. I thought the function I mentioned would be the probability density function. May I ask you how did you come into the conclusion that its the cdf?

Comment: I came to that conclusion based the way you phrased "...the probability that you still need to wait to hear the dog barking after  hours...."  First, you have the word "probability".  That immediately says that you don't have a continuous pdf.  Then there's "after y hours" and plotting the function shows a probability near 1 for small hours and probabilities near 0 for large hours.  That implies 1 minus a CDF and that the low end should be a probability of 1 and that is fixed by having the weights sum to 1.  (And being a statistician for 45+ years also helps.)

Answer (score 0):

*Note: the probability density function that you have provided does not appear to describe a valid probability distribution. Instead, I will explain the general process of how to solve your problem for any suitable continuous distribution of a similar form.*

The probability density function for the random variable Y that you provided is:

$$f_Y(y)= P(Y=y)=0. 3e^{−0.5} + 0. 6e^{−0.25y}$$

We will assume that this is a valid distribution for the purposes of illustrating the method to solve your problem. Note that since Y is continuous, we define its expectation by the integral:

$$E[Y]=\int_{y} yP(Y=y)dy = \int_{y} 0.3ye^{−0.5} + 0. 6ye^{−0.25y}dy=\mu$$

and similarly, the variance is defined:

$$Var(Y) = E(Y^2)-E(Y)^2=\int_{y} y^2P(Y=y)dy=\Big{(}\int_{y} 0.3y^2e^{−0.5} + 0. 6y^2e^{−0.25y}dy\Big{)}-\mu^2$$

If it turns out that you provided us with wrong probability mass function in the question, then this process can be easily adjusted to suit the new distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This distribution is not a discrete rather a continuous so it will have a probability density function.

Comment: Denoting $y$ to be the number of hours, makes it sound like $y$ is supposed to be discrete. But I'll change my answer, it's quite similar.

Comment: I have updated my answer now @PrannoyMulmi